# How to limit resultset globaly (or by session) in Oracle?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

I try to limit resultset in size without having to change each SQL statement from the app (at least for instance). So adding `ROWNUM` clause to every query is not an option.

I'm looking more or less for some global parameter, or at least a session parameter (like `SET ROWCOUNT` in SQLServer).

The app uses JDBC ressource pool to connect to Oracle, so I can set session-wide parameter in SQL init JDBC pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the [Statement.setMaxRows method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows%28int%29)?  That's a standard JDBC approach that will silently drop rows after the specified maximum number have been fetched.

From a performance standpoint, however, you are likely better served by actually modifying the queries that are sent to the database.  If you do as @MK suggests, you'll be telling the optimizer that you're only going to fetch N rows.  That potentially allows the optimizer to pick a more efficient plan.

Comment: Right, the problem with this is that a) database will still have to find all the rows, it's just JDBC that drops them and b) he would have to go and manually find every place where query is executed.

Comment: @MK - Oracle in general only materializes the results when you fetch them (barring, of course, cases where it has to fetch all the data in order to sort it before it can return the first row).  So you can generally save execution time if you never fetch more than the first N rows.  Not generally as much time as you can if you tell Oracle that you only want the first N rows using a `ROWNUM` clause, of course.  In theory, the JDBC driver could implement `setMaxRows` by adding the `WHERE rownum <= N` clause silently-- no idea if the Oracle JDBC driver actually does that.

Comment: Interesting.  I've certainly seen people add WHERE rownum limit manually to Oracle queries in addition to setMaxRows, but I've never benchmarked it.

Comment: This seems to be the best way to do it, with the heavy downside @MK. suggests : having to manually find all queries (and making this configurable). I'm quite disappointed Oracle don't have such a session-wide property.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there is no way to do it.  You could create an AOP advice which will modify each executeQuery() call by wrapping the query with

```
"select * from ( " + origQuery + " ) where ROWNUM <= 5"
```

but I would hope this is a temporary or test thing we are talking about.

Comment: You need to be careful if you dynamically modify all SQL statements.
There is at least one case where this approach will not work.  For example, `select * from (select 1 a, 2 a from dual);` will cause `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`.  And changing the SQL statement could break some performance tuning methods, such as stored outlines.

Comment: @jonearles agreed, see my remark about this being a temporary or a test thing :)